# class not applying to all html elements in reactjs after adding new data

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { CodeGenerator } from '@babel/generator';

    class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data:[{"type": "Beverages", "sub_types": ["Water", "Coffee"]}]
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            let toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
            for (let i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
            toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
                this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
            });
            }
        }

        callAgain = () => {
            let toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
            for (let i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
                toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
                    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
                });
            }
        }

        appendSecond = () => {
            this.setState(previousState => ({
                data: [...previousState.data,  {"type": "Beveragee2", "sub_types": ["Water", "Coffee"]}]
            }), () => this.callAgain());

        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div style={{ margin:'1cm' }}>
                    <ul id="myUL">
                    {
                        this.state.data.map((d, index) => (
                            <li><span class="caret">{d.type}</span>
                            <ul class="nested">
                            {
                                d.sub_types.map(sub => (
                                    <li>{sub}</li>
                                ))
                            }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        ))
                    }
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.appendSecond}>button</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Test;
```

Hi, here i have shared my Code.

I am just created one tree view using html/css and it is working firsttime when i am clicking the caret icon and it toggles.

But when i am appending one more tree on to my data it is not working the previous tree but, working the last inserted tree.

Please run this code for better understanding. I tried to explain but, not sure you guys got or not what i am trying to say.

Please have a  look.

Comment: Your solution breaks the whole purpose of using React. Use states to update class names.

Comment: You mean have to add different class for each data ?

Comment: Basically, you should use a react click handler, and use it to toggle a state variable that adds the class in the render function. In general, you should always avoid interacting directly with the DOM when working with React.

Comment: Can you please edit the code ? Or share the answer. Not able to understand

Comment: Don't use `class` for css class it is a reserved js word, use className.please bother to read react docs.https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Comment: Yes, its for testing so i ignored. I am looking for solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import React from 'react';

    class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data:[{"type": "Beverages", "sub_types": ["Water", "Coffee"]}],
                actives: []
            }
        }

        appendSecond = () => {
            this.setState(previousState => ({
                data: [...previousState.data,  {"type": "Beveragee"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1), "sub_types": ["Water", "Coffee"]}]
            }));

        }

        handleToggle = (name) => {
            let actives = this.state.actives
            if(actives.includes(name)){
                for(let i=0; i<actives.length; i++){
                if(actives[i] === name){
                    actives.splice(i, 1)
                }   
                }
                this.setState({
                    actives: actives
                })
                return 
            }

            this.setState({
                actives:[...this.state.actives, name]
            });

        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div style={{ margin:'1cm' }}>
                    <ul id="myUL">
                    {
                        this.state.data.map((d, index) => (
                            <li><span class="caret" onClick={() => this.handleToggle(d.type)}>{d.type}</span>
                            <ul class={this.state.actives.includes(d.type) ? "nested active" : "nested"}>
                            {
                                d.sub_types.map(sub => (
                                    <li>{sub}</li>
                                ))
                            }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        ))
                    }
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.appendSecond}>button</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of things wrong about your approach to everything.

1. When using React you shouldn't touch the DOM directly, It is the job of React to manipulate the DOM while you just set the conditions in which it should update.

example code below is **wrong** in react and none of it is necessary:

```
componentDidMount(){   
       let toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
       for (let i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
        toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
            this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
       }); 
   }
}
```

Instead of the above code, you can simply set the `state` data and reference the state in your `render()`. You should read more about how React works from the official docs or other resources.

2. You can declare your menu items in the state like below:

```
this.state = {
    menuItems: [
      {
        order: 0,
        title: 'beverages',
        submenu: [{
            title: 'water',
            sub: []
          },
          {
            title: 'Coffee',
            sub: []
          }],
        isActive: false
      },
      {
        order: 1,
        title: 'cereal',
        submenu: [],
        isActive: false
      }
    ]
 }
```

Then map over the menuItems state in your render. You will then add conditions based on `isActive` state.

You would also need a toggle function to set the isActive state to true or false.

3. Instead of `class="caret"` use `className="caret"` React reserves the name `class` for class components.

I hope you get the idea.